# Is it possible to tweak the alignment of an equation when it is broken using breqn?

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, breqn

I have a looooooooong `displaymath` that I'm using [breqn](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn) to break into smaller chunks.  As there are no actual relation symbols, I've manually added `\allowbreak` everywhere I'd be happy for one to occur (if I get this to look right, I'll trim the code a bit).  But the resulting display is not quite how I would like it, and I can't see in the documentation how one can tell the `dmath` environment about how it should look.  Specifically, the lines seem to be left-justified *except* the first which has an overhand.  I think it would look best if this overhand were eliminated and the whole lot were left-justified.  Centring would be an acceptable alternative.

Of course, I could do the whole thing manually - now that I know where `breqn` *would* put the breaks, I can put them in by hand.  But that just *feels wrong*!

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{dmath*}
d_1 c_4 d_1^{-1} c_1^{-1},\;\allowbreak
d_1 c_3^{-1} d_2^{-1} c_3,\;\allowbreak
d_2 a_2 d_2^{-1} a_3^{-1},\;\allowbreak
d_2 a_3^{-1} d_3^{-1} a_3,\;\allowbreak
d_3 c_2 d_3^{-1} c_3^{-1},\;\allowbreak
d_3 c_1^{-1} d_4^{-1} c_1,\;\allowbreak
d_4 b_3 d_4^{-1} b_4^{-1},\;\allowbreak
d_4 b_3^{-1} d_5^{-1} b_3,\;\allowbreak
d_5 c_1 d_6^{-1} c_1^{-1},\;\allowbreak
d_6 c_2^{-1} d_6^{-1} c_1,\;\allowbreak
d_6 a_3 d_7^{-1} a_3^{-1},\;\allowbreak
d_7 a_2^{-1} d_7^{-1} a_1,\;\allowbreak
d_7 c_3 d_8^{-1} c_3^{-1},\;\allowbreak
d_8 c_4^{-1} d_8^{-1} c_3,\;\allowbreak
d_8 b_1 d_8^{-1} b_2^{-1},\;\allowbreak
d_8 b_1^{-1} d_1^{-1} b_1,\;\allowbreak
b_2 a_4 b_2^{-1} a_1^{-1},\;\allowbreak
b_2 a_3^{-1} b_3^{-1} a_3,\;\allowbreak
b_4 a_3 b_1^{-1} a_3^{-1},\;\allowbreak
b_1 a_4^{-1} b_1^{-1} a_3
\end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

And here's the result:

[image: misaligned mathematics]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to the *actual* question by digging in the `breqn.sty` file.  Whilst Herbert's answer may be simpler and probably should be used if at all possible, just in case someone else *really* wants to do exactly what I described, here's how to do it.  The reverse-indentation is controlled by a length called `\eqmargin` and setting that to `0pt` removes it.  To make this setting local to a given environment, it can be passed in using the `style` key in an optional argument.

Here's the three versions: the original, Herbert's suggestion, and then this version, with a double dose of `lipsum` fore and aft to show how the line width works.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\semicolon=\;
\renewcommand{\;}{\semicolon\allowbreak}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{dmath*}
d_1 c_4 d_1^{-1} c_1^{-1},\;
d_1 c_3^{-1} d_2^{-1} c_3,\;
d_2 a_2 d_2^{-1} a_3^{-1},\;
d_2 a_3^{-1} d_3^{-1} a_3,\;
d_3 c_2 d_3^{-1} c_3^{-1},\;
d_3 c_1^{-1} d_4^{-1} c_1,\;
d_4 b_3 d_4^{-1} b_4^{-1},\;
d_4 b_3^{-1} d_5^{-1} b_3,\;
d_5 c_1 d_6^{-1} c_1^{-1},\;
d_6 c_2^{-1} d_6^{-1} c_1,\;
d_6 a_3 d_7^{-1} a_3^{-1},\;
d_7 a_2^{-1} d_7^{-1} a_1,\;
d_7 c_3 d_8^{-1} c_3^{-1},\;
d_8 c_4^{-1} d_8^{-1} c_3,\;
d_8 b_1 d_8^{-1} b_2^{-1},\;
d_8 b_1^{-1} d_1^{-1} b_1,\;
b_2 a_4 b_2^{-1} a_1^{-1},\;
b_2 a_3^{-1} b_3^{-1} a_3,\;
b_4 a_3 b_1^{-1} a_3^{-1},\;
b_1 a_4^{-1} b_1^{-1} a_3.
\end{dmath*}

\begingroup
\raggedright
\(d_1 c_4 d_1^{-1} c_1^{-1}\), 
\(d_1 c_3^{-1} d_2^{-1} c_3\), 
\(d_2 a_2 d_2^{-1} a_3^{-1}\), 
\(d_2 a_3^{-1} d_3^{-1} a_3\), 
\(d_3 c_2 d_3^{-1} c_3^{-1}\), 
\(d_3 c_1^{-1} d_4^{-1} c_1\), 
\(d_4 b_3 d_4^{-1} b_4^{-1}\), 
\(d_4 b_3^{-1} d_5^{-1} b_3\), 
\(d_5 c_1 d_6^{-1} c_1^{-1}\), 
\(d_6 c_2^{-1} d_6^{-1} c_1\), 
\(d_6 a_3 d_7^{-1} a_3^{-1}\), 
\(d_7 a_2^{-1} d_7^{-1} a_1\), 
\(d_7 c_3 d_8^{-1} c_3^{-1}\), 
\(d_8 c_4^{-1} d_8^{-1} c_3\), 
\(d_8 b_1 d_8^{-1} b_2^{-1}\), 
\(d_8 b_1^{-1} d_1^{-1} b_1\), 
\(b_2 a_4 b_2^{-1} a_1^{-1}\), 
\(b_2 a_3^{-1} b_3^{-1} a_3\), 
\(b_4 a_3 b_1^{-1} a_3^{-1}\), 
\(b_1 a_4^{-1} b_1^{-1} a_3\).
\endgroup

\begin{dmath*}[style={\eqmargin=0pt}]
d_1 c_4 d_1^{-1} c_1^{-1},\;
d_1 c_3^{-1} d_2^{-1} c_3,\;
d_2 a_2 d_2^{-1} a_3^{-1},\;
d_2 a_3^{-1} d_3^{-1} a_3,\;
d_3 c_2 d_3^{-1} c_3^{-1},\;
d_3 c_1^{-1} d_4^{-1} c_1,\;
d_4 b_3 d_4^{-1} b_4^{-1},\;
d_4 b_3^{-1} d_5^{-1} b_3,\;
d_5 c_1 d_6^{-1} c_1^{-1},\;
d_6 c_2^{-1} d_6^{-1} c_1,\;
d_6 a_3 d_7^{-1} a_3^{-1},\;
d_7 a_2^{-1} d_7^{-1} a_1,\;
d_7 c_3 d_8^{-1} c_3^{-1},\;
d_8 c_4^{-1} d_8^{-1} c_3,\;
d_8 b_1 d_8^{-1} b_2^{-1},\;
d_8 b_1^{-1} d_1^{-1} b_1,\;
b_2 a_4 b_2^{-1} a_1^{-1},\;
b_2 a_3^{-1} b_3^{-1} a_3,\;
b_4 a_3 b_1^{-1} a_3^{-1},\;
b_1 a_4^{-1} b_1^{-1} a_3.
\end{dmath*}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: breqn with no initial indent]

Comment: Thanks! I had tried to follow what is going on in `breqn.sty` some time ago, but it is tough. Someone should compile a list of all the relevant lengths...

Answer (score 4):

Can't you use it this way?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\raggedright
$d_1 c_4 d_1^{-1} c_1^{-1},$
$d_1 c_3^{-1} d_2^{-1} c_3,$
$d_2 a_2 d_2^{-1} a_3^{-1},$
$d_2 a_3^{-1} d_3^{-1} a_3,$
$d_3 c_2 d_3^{-1} c_3^{-1},$
$d_3 c_1^{-1} d_4^{-1} c_1,$
$d_4 b_3 d_4^{-1} b_4^{-1},$
$d_4 b_3^{-1} d_5^{-1} b_3,$
$d_5 c_1 d_6^{-1} c_1^{-1},$
$d_6 c_2^{-1} d_6^{-1} c_1,$
$d_6 a_3 d_7^{-1} a_3^{-1},$
$d_7 a_2^{-1} d_7^{-1} a_1,$
$d_7 c_3 d_8^{-1} c_3^{-1},$
$d_8 c_4^{-1} d_8^{-1} c_3,$
$d_8 b_1 d_8^{-1} b_2^{-1},$
$d_8 b_1^{-1} d_1^{-1} b_1,$
$b_2 a_4 b_2^{-1} a_1^{-1},$
$b_2 a_3^{-1} b_3^{-1} a_3,$
$b_4 a_3 b_1^{-1} a_3^{-1},$
$b_1 a_4^{-1} b_1^{-1} a_3$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know, that never occurred to me!  I guess I need to stick it in a parbox to centre it as a whole on the page, but that's easy enough.  Still, I'm curious as to why breqn behaves as it does.  Thanks!

Comment: If there had been an equal sign later, then the indent would save readability, making clear where the left-hand side started. (just my impression)